# fundamental group of a graph is free

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, group-actions

Let $X$ be a connected graph, and $T$ its maximal tree. Via covering spaces and deck-transformations, how one can prove that $\pi_1(X)= \pi_1(X/T)$?

Comment: Why do you want to do this via covering spaces?

Comment: because I want to avoid the homotopy extension property.. if there is another way tell me please

Answer (score 2):

Without using them you know that a tree is contractible and thus you get your thesis since $X\to X/T$ is an homotopy equivalence (it's the quotient modulo a contractible subcomplex).

Comment: ok..  it's homotopy equivalence because it's the quotient modulo a contractible subcomplex.. can u refer me to a book to prove that?

Comment: Algebraic Topology by Hatcher

Comment: It's proposition 0.17 in Hatcher's book, but you still need some kind of homotopy extension.